# How to plot a specific contour line in Matlab

Tags: matlab, contourf

Consider this example:

```
X = 0:0.01:1;
Y = 0:0.01:1;
[x,y] = meshgrid(X,Y);
z = sin(x.*y);
contourf(x,y,z,'ShowText','on')
```

[image]

The contour's values are determined automatically. How can I plot specifi contour lines with specific values like [0.1,0.3,0.44,0.63,0.78,0.89]?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If the desired values are

```
  v = [0.1,0.3,0.44,0.63,0.78,0.89]
```

then we have

```
X = 0:0.01:1;
Y = 0:0.01:1;
[x,y] = meshgrid(X,Y);
z = sin(x.*y);
contourf(x,y,z,[0.1,0.3,0.44,0.63,0.78,0.89],'ShowText','on')
```

the place of vector 'v' must be right after 'z'.

Comment: This works only if specific contour line is already there.